# Complete options even after a non-option argument in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have zsh completion rules for my custom script `h`:

```
#compdef h

_arguments -S : \
    '-A+:' \
    '-B+:' \
    '-C+:' \
    '-i' \
    '-w'
```

My custom script takes the options shown above, and also one or more arbitrary strings. The completion works when no string is given:

```
h <TAB>
-A  -B  -C  -i  -w
```

But once i provide the string, the completion no longer works:

```
h foo -<TAB>
```

nothing.

How can I use completion even after I have provided one or more strings?

## UPDATE:

I have added `'*:string:'` as suggested by @Gilles

```
#compdef h

_arguments -S : \
    '*:string:' \
    '-A+:' \
    '-B+:' \
    '-C+:' \
    '-i' \
    '--color' \
    '-w'
```

But the completion behaves strangely. When I do:

```
h some text -<TAB>
```

it actually lists me available options, but does not complete them.

When I do:

```
h some text --co<TAB>
```

it shows available --color option, but does not complete the rest, even though the option is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the depths of `zshcompsys(1)` one might find the `-A`
option to `_arguments`

```
-A pat Do not complete options after the first non-option argument
       on the line. pat is a pattern matching all strings which are
       not to be taken as arguments. For example, to make _arguments
       stop completing options after the first normal argument, but
       ignoring all strings starting with a hyphen even if they are
       not described by one of the optspecs, the form is `-A "-*"'.
```

which is not helped by the negations. Anyways, the pattern `*` appears
to mean that "everything is not taken as an argument" therefore the
options should complete following a non-option argument:

```
#compdef h
local ret=1
_arguments -A "*" -S : \
    '-A+:' \
    '-B+:' \
    '-C+:' \
    '-i' \
    '-w' \
    && ret=0
return $ret
```

Usage, assuming the `_h` completion script is in `~/.zsh/functions`:

```
% zsh -f
lion% print $fpath
lion% fpath=( ~/.zsh/functions $fpath )
lion% autoload -U compinit
lion% compinit
lion% h -w foo -
-A  -B  -C  -i
```

with the cursor right after the `-` ZSH completes the available options.
Confirm that the completion script is up (*after* tabbing on the
command) via:

```
lion% which _h
_h () {
        local ret=1
        _arguments -A "*" -S : '-A+:' '-B+:' '-C+:' '-i' '-w' && ret=0
        return $ret
}
```

Comment: thank you,  but this change doe snot seem to help. It behaves same as before.

Comment: does it work under a minimal shell configuration?

Comment: I follow the steps exactly, but this still does not work.

Comment: I think `-A "*"` should be equivalent to not using `-A` at all. Experimentally, I confirm that it doesn't seem to make a difference. What does make a difference @400theCat is adding completions for non-option arguments `*:string:`, but that also means that zsh won't automatically insert a `-` if you press TAB on an empty word, which is not necessarily desirable.

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' - thank you, but when I add `*:string:` it behaves strangely. Please see my update.